# How should I develop Google OAuth 2 for iOS, and also with original google sign in UI?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, oauth-2.0, google-reader

I am going to write an app for google services, but I stuck at the first step: `let user sign in for google's services`.

I can find `gtm-OAuth2` library from Google's code base. But the problem for that is I don't know how to load Google's default sign in page - like some apps are doing (below is the screenshot):

[image: Google signin page]

Anyone gives me some hints?

Where can I load this page for iphone and how then to get the login info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page is provided by: [the Google OAuth 2 login flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp)